# Delete a dictionary item in a json file Using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value

I have a sample json file in python.

```json
[
  {
    "WHO": "Joe",
    "WEEK": [
      {
        "NUMBER": 3,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 18.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 19.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Car",
            "AMOUNT": 20.00
          }
        ]
```

So in this I have to remove/delete the whole dictionary of car.
Is there any way to make this as an exception using `try-except` statement.

I tried using `POP()` and `DEL()` function in **Python** but it didn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "make this an exception"? Could you add an example to your question

Comment: As you can see in my answer you can iterate over an enumerated list using the index to delete your item you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `try-except` block but just load your `json` data and iterate over the fields looking for your `Car`.

First save your `json` as a file named `"jsondata.json"`

*jsondata.json*

```
[{ "WHO": "Joe", "WEEK": [{"NUMBER": 3,"EXPENSE":[
    {   "WHAT": "Beer",
        "AMOUNT": 18.00
    },
    {
        "WHAT": "Food",
        "AMOUNT": 12.00
    },
    {
        "WHAT": "Food",
        "AMOUNT": 19.00
    },
    {
       "WHAT": "Car",
       "AMOUNT": 20.00
    }
    ]}]}
]
```

And then a small working example:

```
import json

def get_car(jdata):
    for idx, expense in enumerate(jdata[0]['WEEK'][0]['EXPENSE']):
        if expense['WHAT'] == 'Car':
            del jdata[0]['WEEK'][0]['EXPENSE'][idx]
            print('REMOVING CAR!')
            return jdata 
    print('NO CAR FOUND!')
    return jdata


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #loads json
    with open('jsondata.json') as fh:
        jsondata = fh.read()
    myjson = json.loads(jsondata)
    print(myjson)
    print('Running function...')
    myjson_after = get_car(myjson)
    print(myjson_after)
```

If your data is sanitized and you don't have irregularities in formatting or malformed information then just loop over the `EXPENSE` field checking for items that match what it is you are looking for.  When you find it having `enumerate` give you the index of the `"Car"` field you can then `del` on that item and return your new **json** data.